# VBO + glBufferData crash when size too high

Tags: c, opengl, vbo

I'm trying to get a simple VBO running. But when i call

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*vertexcount, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

it just crashes, but only when vertexcount is over 1531. And yes, the "vertices" array stores, or rather there is enough space allocated, for more then 1531 elements.
This is my Vertex struct:

```
typedef struct{
    float x, y, z;
    float nx, ny, nz;
    float u, v;
}Vertex, vertex;
```

So it should be 32 bytes.
32bytes * 1531 = 48992bytes = 48kb.

But 48kb doesnt seem to be too high for a normal VBO? I dont understand what is happening.

Edit:

Windows Xp 32bit Service Pack 3

Nvidia GeForce 9800GT 1024mb

Edit2:
Short Version of my complete Code:
(interesting part is at the bottom)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <wglew.h>
#include <gl3.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))

typedef struct{
    float x, y, z;
float nx, ny, nz;
float u, v;
}Vertex, vertex;

typedef struct{
    int first, second, third;
}VertexIndex, vertexindex, vindex, Vindex;

typedef struct{
    unsigned int vao;
    unsigned int vertexcount, indexcount;
}Mesh, mesh;

typedef struct{
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hdc;
    HGLRC hrc;
}GLWindow, Window, window;

void WindowShenanigans(Window *w, HINSTANCE *hinstance, WNDPROC WindowProc)
{
    HWND tmp_hwnd;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    ZeroMemory(&wndclass, sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    wndclass.style  = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_GLOBALCLASS;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;    
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wndclass.hIcon = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance  = *hinstance;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = "glclass";
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_APPWORKSPACE);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;

    if(RegisterClass(&wndclass) == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    ShowCursor(TRUE);

    tmp_hwnd = CreateWindowA  ( "glclass",
                            "bla",
                            WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU,
                            0, 0,
                            600,
                            800,
                            HWND_DESKTOP,
                            NULL,
                            hinstance,
                            NULL);

    w->hwnd = tmp_hwnd;

    unsigned int PixelFormat;
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 32;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    w->hdc = GetDC(w->hwnd);

    PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(w->hdc, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(w->hdc, PixelFormat, &pfd);

    int attrib[] =
    {
            WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
            WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
            WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
            0
    }; //OpenGL Context

    HGLRC tmphrc = wglCreateContext(w->hdc);

    wglMakeCurrent (w->hdc, tmphrc);

    PFNWGLCREATEBUFFERREGIONARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB =      (PFNWGLCREATEBUFFERREGIONARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress( "wglCreateContextAttribsARB" );
    w->hrc = (HGLRC)wglCreateContextAttribsARB( w->hdc, 0, (UINT)attrib ) ;

    ShowWindow(w->hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(w->hwnd);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
        }
        break;
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
        }
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
        }
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

BOOL ProcessMessage(MSG *msg)
{
    if(GetMessage(msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(msg);
        DispatchMessage(msg);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void DataUpload(Mesh *m, Vindex *indices, Vertex *vertices)
{
    unsigned int vbo, index_vbo;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m->vao);
    glBindVertexArray(m->vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &index_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int)*3500, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    //  MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "3..2..1..", "", MB_OK);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*3500, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //  MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "YEA", "", MB_OK);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(float)*3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(float)*6));
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void MeshGenerate(Mesh *m, float x, float y, float z)
{
        int i;
        Vertex *vertices;
        Vindex *indices;
        m->vertexcount = 3500;
        m->indexcount = 3500;
        vertices = malloc(3500*sizeof(vertex));
        indices = malloc(3500*sizeof(vindex));

        for(i = 0; i<3500; i++)
        {
            vertices[i].x = 1.0f;
            vertices[i].y = 1.0f;
            vertices[i].z = 1.0f;
            vertices[i].nx = 1.0f;
            vertices[i].ny = 1.0f;
            vertices[i].nz = 1.0f;
            vertices[i].u = 1.0f;
            vertices[i].v = 1.0f;
        }
        for(i = 0; i<3500; i++)
        {
            indices[i].first = 1;
            indices[i].second = 1;
            indices[i].third = 1;
        }
        DataUpload(m, vertices, indices);
        return;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hprevinstance, LPSTR lpcmdline, int nshowcmd)
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL isActive = 1;
    window w;
    WindowShenanigans(&w, &hinstance, WindowProc);

    glewInit();

    Mesh m;
    MeshGenerate(&m, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    while(isActive == 1)
    {
        SwapBuffers(w.hdc);
        isActive = ProcessMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Is it just a good old segfault?

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See if mallocing the same memory helps?

Comment: VBO's of multiple MB's work fine on my machine. I suspect the size just happens to expose some other bug.

Comment: What platform?  I would think that when the GPU driver trys to read the data stored in the array 'vertices' it is hitting some sort barrier.  It's too hard to tell with out more details.

Comment: Does the crash happen when you pass NULL as the pointer?  If that is the case it is a driver issue and you can't allocate a VBO that large.

Comment: If I pass NULL everything is fine. So my vertices array must be wrong.

Comment: The signature reads `void DataUpload(Mesh *m, Vindex *indices, Vertex *vertices)`, the callsite reads `DataUpload(m, vertices, indices);`. You sure this is right?

Comment: Thanks dude :D. That was the problem. Also it was really dump mistake <_<. Well, it works perfectly now.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a similar problem and it was totally my fault as well, did not even consider there could be something wrong with my code, so it was a big help from your question (+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ogl.c: In function `MeshGenerate':
```

ogl.c:200: warning: passing arg 2 of `DataUpload' from incompatible pointer type
ogl.c:200: warning: passing arg 3 of`DataUpload' from incompatible pointer type

I don't have glew installed so I can't get the sample to properly work.  But this is definitely an issue.

```
DataUpload(m, vertices, indices);
```

It should be

```
DataUpload(m, indices, vertices);
```

Comment: yep, i didnt notice that <_<. Works fine now